# Configuring a remote repository over ssh (Artifactory)

Tags: maven, artifactory

Is there any way to define a remote repository over ssh? 
I mean  - scp://blah/blah...

This repository is needed for resolving new artifacts only and not for deployment.

I know that there's a "wagon-ssh-external" plugin but all examples I found use it directly from pom or settings.xml, no example of artifactory configuration.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not using http(s) ? Much more simpler...

Comment: I have only ssh access to that repo, It has to be over ssh.

Comment: Sound really strange...May be you need to add the wagon-ssh deps to the maven installation lib folder ?

Comment: why do you need ssh, if you are using artifactory, you can use REST API to upload/download the packages. If simple case, you can use artifactory jenkins plugin

Comment: Hi... I need ssh because I'm trying to use the .m2 at my work station, as another maven repo.
The only connection I have to my work is ssh (through a reverse tunnel).
I've solved my problem by tunneling to Nexus at work through my work desktop(don't no need ssh to copy artifacts any more), but the question still remains.

Comment: is https://maven.apache.org/wagon/wagon-providers/wagon-ssh-external/ ? it is maven plugin not artifactory plugin? what is it related with artifactory ?